# How to find out my plan to create a web app in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a webapp as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-continuous-deployment-github#to-create-the-web-app). The group is created. Then, I omit the step of **creating** a plan, since I already have a subscription allowing me to do that (which I can confirm by creating the app from the GUI and picking which plan/subscription I want to use).

When I execute

```
az webapp create --resource-group my-group `
                 --name app-lication `
                 --plan "Enterprise MSDN Dev Test"
```

it fails, since the plan isn't recognized. I tried with different names and GUIDS (those I see when I `az login`, for instance etc.) but nothing seems to work out. How do I obtain the correct referece to my plans/subscriptions so I can pass it as the last parameter in the command above?

Comment: The plan name should be the name of an App Service Plan you’ve created.

Comment: I believe you’re confusing between a subscription and App Service Plan. An App Service Plan is a resource inside a resource group in your subscription which will host your web apps.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans

Comment: @GauravMantri It's not improbable that I confused stuff. Are you saying that I **will have to** create a plan (i.e. app service plan) that appears as one of the items listed for the current resource group? And **then** use it to create a webapp? It's nothing to do with the **payment** plan, being a subscription, then. Correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'd post that as a reply to be accepted. The other user was probably mislead by my confusion and answered something that is beneficial to have but doesn't quite resolve my specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be more reliable to pass the Plan ResourceId than the name, this specifically caters for scenarios when the plan exists in a different resource group.

The naming convention of your plan in the question is typical of an Azure Subscription. Ensure you do have a properly created App Service Plan to use.

```bash
AppServicePlanID=$(az appservice plan show -n SharedAppServicePlan -g MyASPRG --query "id" --out tsv) 
az webapp create -g MyResourceGroup -p "$AppServicePlanID" -n MyUniqueAppName
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-create-examples

Comment: Is the command in your answer a one-liner? Or did it get distorted in the paste-in process?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, an App Service Plan is different from a Subscription.

An App Service Plan is a kind of resource which will host your web apps. Think of it as a VM where you can host multiple web apps.

What you have to do is first create a new App Service Plan using [`az appservice plan create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-create) and use its name/id when creating web app.

You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans.